# Getting Attribute Values stored within application scope

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, web, backend

I am storing unknown number of attribute names and values from user within application scope. There are some application specific attributes within application scope ( So when you type Enumeration en = getServletContext.getAttributeNames(); , it contains some other attributes that you haven't set but system specific). My question is how can i get those attribute values that i receive from users which i store within application scope (without application specific attributes which contains system information etc) ?

Scenario could be like this: 
User input:

hello

Output:

hello

User input: good times

Output:

hello

good times

User input:

bad times

output:

hello

good times

bad times
..
..

P.S It is **essential** to store those input values within application scope.

Answer (score 0):

you can did that using `ArrayList<String>` declared as global variable and add user input every time to that Array List and printout all array list elements.

Hope that helps.

Comment: that idea came to my mind too, but it is like you store the same information twice and no meaning of application scope attributes

Comment: what about using static class that take care of all data and behavior of that  context ?